# azure data studio to expand wildcard as column name feature

Tags: azure-data-studio, wildcard-expansion

I knew there was an introduction for expanding wildcard. However, I cannot do this. Does anyone know what is the feature name to amend to the corresponding shortcut key? Or this feature was removed due to some reason? BTW it seems that I cannot hit ctrl+space by toggling keyboard shortcut troubleshooting. It will prompt dispatch issue.

> [2023-07-30 20:54:27.745] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
> [2023-07-30 20:54:27.745] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
> [2023-07-30 20:54:27.746] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
> [2023-07-30 20:54:28.197] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.

[Eariler tutorial](https://www.andrewvillazon.com/auzre-data-studio-tips-tricks/#expand--to-all-columns-in-a-select-)

It seems ADS already has it some time ago, but I cannot find it in the release note or how to use it in the official site.
[Detail feature explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/sqltoolsservice/pull/1270)
[Related committed log](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/pull/17528)